# Laravel save Eloquent along with relationships

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I added relations to a model. The structure being the following:

> A `Structure` Model `hasMany` `Managers`. Each `Manager` `hasMany` `Employees`

So I get this done using the following code:

```
$structure->name = "Something";
$manager1 = new Manager;
$manager2 = new Manager;

$manager1->name = "Man One";
$manager2->name = "Man Two";

$emp1 = new Employee;
$emp2 = new Employee;
$emp3 = new Employee;

$emp1->name....
...
....

$manager1->add($emp1);
$manager1->add($emp2);
$manager2->add($emp3);

$structure->add($manager1);
$structure->add($manager2);

.... //Some calculations & necessary processing to fill up other properties of $structure.

///Now I have to save $structure..
$structure->push()
```

But it returns an error that `$manager` needs value of foreign key (`structure_id`) for obvious reasons. `$structure->managers()->save()` does help but saving all the **relations and their relations** is cumbersome.

Hence I need to know the method of saving the whole structure model at once.

Comment: You asked what I had been searching for a lot of time.

Comment: You need to save structure model first, then below that use what you have `$structure->managers()->save()` to save your managers. Probably best to wrap it in a transaction so if one fails, the inserts are rolledback.

Comment: @andrew-nolan I expected something more efficient than `$structure->push()` because saving the relations separately is cumbersome

Comment: That's ActiveRecord. You can deal with it or use a tool that suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use saveMany (you have to pass an array of Manager object):

```
$structure->managers()->saveMany(array($managers));
```

Or (you have to pass an array of arrays with object data declared in the $fillable array in the Manager model):

```
$structure->managers()->createMany(array($managersData));
$structure->save();
```